# Automatically extracting data from csv file into specific matrix position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a rather large csv file that I need the program to read, then input the data into the correct position of a zero matrix. Sample of csv block (also attached file):

```
 Sector,Service,Data_Point
Bio,Electricity NonEmitting,0
NEElectricity,Electricity NonEmitting,0.5
RE,Electricity NonEmitting,0
Electricity,Electricity NonEmitting,-1
Bio,Electricity Bio,0.8
NEElectricity,Electricity Bio,0
RE,Electricity Bio,0.04
Electricity,Electricity Bio,-2
Bio,Electricity BECCS,0.84
NEElectricity,Electricity BECCS,0
RE,Electricity BECCS,0.4
Electricity,Electricity BECCS,-1
Bio,Ammonia HB,0
Electricity,Ammonia HB,2.8
RE,Ammonia HB,0.06
Ammonia,Ammonia HB,-1
Bio,Biofuel TBD,0.30
Electricity,Biofuel TBD,0.02
RE,Biofuel TBD,0.012
Electricity,CarUse BEV,0.5
RE,CarUse BEV,0
CarUse,CarUse BEV,-1
Hydrogen,CarUse HFCEV,0.2
RE,CarUse HFCEV,0
CarUse,CarUse HFCEV,-1
Bio,NET DAC,0
NEElectricity,NET DAC,10.5
RE,NET DAC,-1
```

The problem is that I need it to be able to sort the data based on the Sector and Service columns. I.e. Sector = rows, Service = columns in the matrix. So if the program reads Sector as Bio: row = 1, and Service as Electricity NonEmitting: column 1, it inputs the corresponding number from Data_Point (in this case Data_Point is '0') into row 1 column 1 of the matrix. Or if it reads Sector as NEElectricity: row = 2, but service as Electricity NonEmitting again: column 1, the corresponding Data_Point '0.5' is inputted into row 2 column 1 of the matrix.

Below I have written code that automatically generates a zero matrix based on the number of unique elements in the Sector and Service columns. I just cannot figure out how to sort the values into the correct matrix position, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sector = pd.read_csv('Coeff_Sample.csv', usecols=["Sector"])
matrix_column = int(sector.nunique())

service = pd.read_csv('Coeff_Sample.csv', usecols=["Service"])
matrix_row = int(service.nunique())

coeff_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_row, matrix_column))
```

Best regards

Comment: if you have read the file into dataframes, describe those rather than the csv

Comment: Do you ever have your data all at once in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Matrix]

Is that the kind of matrix u wanted to create?

I created this matrix without pandas with the following source code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

rows = []
columns = []
all_rows = []

with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        columns.append(row['Sector'])
        rows.append(row['Service'])
        all_rows.append(row)

rows_set = set(rows)
columns_set = set(columns)
coeff_matrix = np.full((len(rows_set)+1, len(columns_set)+1), 0).tolist()

row_list = list(rows_set)
columns_list = list(columns_set)

for idx, x in enumerate(columns_list):
    coeff_matrix[0][idx+1] = x

for idy, y in enumerate(row_list):
    coeff_matrix[idy+1][0] = y

for e in all_rows:
    sector = e['Sector']
    service = e['Service']
    value = e['Data_Point']
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(coeff_matrix):
        if row[0] == service:
            row_index = row_idx
    for column_idx, column in enumerate(coeff_matrix[0]):
        if column == sector:
            column_index = column_idx

    coeff_matrix[row_index][column_index] = value

np_coeff_matrix = np.asarray(coeff_matrix)
```

But it got a lot of loops inside. Maybe there are ways to be faster with that task using pandas or list/np.array functions.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me solve the problem! I was wondering if it is possible to use a different function than set (after first for loop), since each time the program is run, the arrangement of the rows and columns changes. Is there a way of solving this problem that maintains the order of the elements? Again, thank you for the help. :)

Comment: Nevermind! Solved it using the ordered-set package (https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/).